# How to get a value of the checkbox in a GridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have made a C# windows forms project...
How to get a value of the checkbox in a GridView - C# winforms

I add a gridview to the form...

the first column (with index 0) is checkbox button column...

I used the next code to access the checkbox value:

`dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString();`

but it didn't work...

and when I try to execute:

`MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[0, 0].ValueType.ToString());`

I got type.boolean...

so, How can I get the value of the checkbox...

Comment: I haven't worked with winforms in awhile... is it possible though that the bool type your getting is the checked/unchecked flag of the check box?

Comment: we need telepathic mind-reader here to get what means `it didn't work`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `FormattedValue` instead of `Value`

```
bool isChecked = (bool)dataGridView1[0, 0].FormattedValue;
```

Comment: it always take me to Programs.cs and highlight: Application.Run(new Form1()); and say: Object reference not set to an instance of an object... now, I am thinking thats a visual studio problem!!??

Answer (score 0):

Just tried...

Made a form with a datagridview with 1 column (checkbox)
added a row then called

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString());
```

shows "True" for me.

Probably just a casting issue.

like Hans says use

```
bool a = (bool)dataGridView1[0, 0].Value
```

Comment: I've made a new project has a form include a gridview with one column is just a checkbox... and execute this:
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);
 MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString());
but its still give me the same error

Comment: In my test, I just opened the form, created 3 or 4 rows of data, and then executed my MessageBox code on a button. Try actually using the control instead of typing "dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2); " to fill it. Then once you see a handful of rows populated it shouldn't error out.

Comment: I still think you dont have a row there, so ... whever you are querying the value, replace it with this snippit to help diagnose... `MessageBox.Show("My dgv has this many rows: " + dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString()); dataGridView1.Rows.Add(true); MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString()); MessageBox.Show("My dgv has this many rows: " + dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());`

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting but I am a newb at Stackoverflow responses.